# TypeLoadException when using Autofac.Mvc5 (3.2.0) Integration

Tags: autofac, asp.net-mvc-5.1

Getting the TypeLoadException when using some of the registration extension methods.

```
builder.RegisterModelBinders(Assembly);
builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();
builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
```

The following respective exceptions are thrown, however `builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly)` works fine.

```
TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacModelBinderProvider.GetBinder(System.Type)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.
    at Autofac.Integration.Mvc.RegistrationExtensions.RegisterModelBinders(ContainerBuilder builder, Assembly[] modelBinderAssemblies)

TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacModelBinderProvider.GetBinder(System.Type)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.
    at Autofac.Integration.Mvc.RegistrationExtensions.RegisterModelBinderProvider(ContainerBuilder builder)

TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacFilterProvider'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.
    at Autofac.Integration.Mvc.RegistrationExtensions.RegisterFilterProvider(ContainerBuilder builder)
```

Here are what the relevant packages packages.config look like:

```
<package id="Autofac" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Autofac.Mvc5" version="3.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Autofac.Wcf" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

If it's any consolation, the previous `Autofac.Mvc5` package was throwing the same error.

These are the binding redirects for Autofac:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Autofac" publicKeyToken="17863af14b0044da" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: The classes mentioned in the exceptions are marked with the appropriate security attributes and Code Analysis is not reporting any errors for that project. I also tested the same code with the latest packages and did not see the problem. Do you have any <bindingRedirect/> entries in your configuration file?

Comment: @AlexMeyer-Gleaves Yes, I've appended the bindingRedirect section to my question. I'm guessing these need to be updated to 3.3.0.0, or removed since the codebase is compiled with the latest version anyway. I will experiment and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexMeyer-Gleaves I updated the binding redirect to 3.3.0.0 and that caused the application to not compile, the version is 3.0.0.0. In the test, I'm running it in x64, would that make a difference? I also tried removing all of the binding redirects for Autofac entirely and that did not work either.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error after upgrading from MVC 4 to MVC 5 , it didn't update the nuget package for autofac mvc integration which was stil on mvc 4 , so uninstall/reinstall under nuget of all autofac libraries fixed this error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I rebuilt the test project's .csproj and the test passes now, I have not isolated the exact issue. If I find it, I will post it here.